# Viterbi algorithm for object tracking

Tags: algorithms

I want to solve a problem of object tracking along time.
The problem is - I have a sequence of images, and I need to find and track the creation of the objects, than their movement, and than their disappearance. There can be up to 3 objects overall, and sometimes there are less, or none. Another limitation is that for consecutive images there is a maximum distance that an object can move.

The practice I use is - estimating the locations for the objects in each image separately (using a neural network), up to 3 locations per image, and than filtering out clear mistakes (random locations with no continuation along time).

After a little research, I found that with some effort I can translate this problem into a hidden Markov model, and this one can be solved with Viterbi algorithm. The problem is that for each image there are more than 100 possible object locations, and with 3 objects we get >= 100000 different states.

My question is whether there exists a designated algorithm for this case of object tracking along time? Or otherwise, if there's a good and efficient way I can fit Viterbi algorithm for this problem?

Thank for any help!

Comment: It would be helpful to see more of the setup of your problem, such as precisely how your hidden Markov model is formulated.  Posting [mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) is usually a good way to convey such details, although it involves learning $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MATLAB take a look at the following two functions (you may also find the examples and references helpful):

- [`assignDetectionsToTracks`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/assigndetectionstotracks.html) Assign detections to tracks for multiobject tracking
- [`matchpairs`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matchpairs.html) Solve linear assignment problem

From openly available codes, I would look into:

- [`scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html) Solve the linear sum assignment problem.
- [`linear_sum_assignment`](https://github.com/ondrejdee/hungarian) Hungarian algorithm (Kuhn-Munkres) for solving the linear sum assignment problem